# Seaborn pointplot x-axis distance between labels does not correspond to actual values

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

Seaborn pointplot does not space x-axis ticks the right way. Here is a MWE

```
import seaborn as sns
df = sns.load_dataset('tips').iloc[:4]
df = df.round({'total_bill':0})
sns.pointplot(data=df, x='total_bill', y='tip')
```

How do I make the spacing of the x-axis labels correspond to their values?

## Edit:

Looks like this is not a bug, but a feature. From the [docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html):

> This function always treats one of the variables as categorical and draws data at ordinal positions (0, 1, … n) on the relevant axis, even when the data has a numeric or date type.

If there is some hack to override this behaviour I'm interested!!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The pointplot is meant for showing interaction between categorial or ordinal.

For your case, plot it twice i guess:

```
sns.lineplot(data=df, x='total_bill', y='tip',marker='o')
```

[image]

Comment: Any (easy) way to show error bars like pointplot does?

Comment: No need to call two functions; just add `marker="o"` to the `lineplot` call.

Comment: ok. edited answer. @YairDaon for errorbar, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38385099/adding-simple-error-bars-to-seaborn-factorplot

Comment: @StupidWolf thanks. I was hoping for something that calculates the errorbars on its own (because I'm lazy). In the meantime, I've found altair, which does the job pretty well.